# ¿Cómo hacer que solo usuarios registrados puedan dar de alta a otros usuarios con Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

¿Cómo puedo hacer que solo los usuarios ya registrados y loggeados puedan crear otros?

Utilicé lo siguiente:

```
prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
```

... y sirvió para que ahora ya no este disponible la ruta **/users/sing_up**, pero si accedo y trato de ir a esa ruta, me despliega el siguiente mensaje:

> Ya has iniciado sesion

¿Cómo puedo hacer que siendo un usuario registrado , pueda registrar a otro?

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
prepend_before_action :authenticate_scope!, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
  #   super
    build_resource({})
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
   end

  # POST /resource
   def create
  #   super
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.persisted?
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
          sign_up(resource_name, resource)
          respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        else
          set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
          expire_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        set_minimum_password_length
        respond_with resource
      end
   end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
   def destroy
     super
   end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
   def cancel
     super
   end

   protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
   def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:tipo_id])
   end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tu `devise_model` es `User`, basta con crear una pagina con un formulario para dar de alta usuarios pidiendo sus datos, y hacer `User.create(...)` en el controlador, en el metodo que recibe el submit de ese formulario.

```
class UserRegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Algun problema al crear el usuario"
      render new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(...) # Tus atributos de User
  end
end
```

En las vistas generas un `form_for` con los campos requeridos para el usuario.

Tomalo como orientacion, pero algo como esto deberia ser suficiente